# Skip statements in case of last item in iterator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.5

I want to skip a number of statements in a for-loop for the last key, value pair in a dict.

Let's assume the next snippet to be the real program:

```
a = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 } # I don't know the exact values, so can't test on them
for key, value in a.iteritems():
    # statements always to be performed

    # statements I want to skip when the current key, value pair is the last unprocessed pair in the dict.

    # maybe some more statements not to be skipped (currently not forseen, but might be added in the future)

# other statements in the program
```

It is probably something simple, but I can't find it.

OK, I could write it using a while-loop:

```
stop = False
b = a.iteritems()
next_key, next_value = b.next()
while True:
    key, value = next_key, next_value
    # do stuff which should be done always

    try:
        next_key, next_value = b.next()
    except StopIteration:
        stop = True
    else:
        # do stuff which should be done for everything but the last pair

    # the future stuff which is not yet forseen.

    if stop:
        break
```

But I think this is ugly code, hence I look for a nice way to do it in a for-loop.
Is this possible?

Oh yes: It needs to work for python 2.7 (and python 2.5 would be a bonus ) since that are the python versions at my work (mainly python 2.7).

Comment: dictionaries aren't ordered. Are you sure you want to skip the last item? or just 1 item?

Comment: The last and with that I mean the last for the for-loop, which might not be the last defined item (so it might be ('b', 2) and not ('c', 3)). The key and value don't care at that moment.

Comment: Maybe to make it more clear: it should work for any iterable

Comment: you cannot make it work for any iterable with a `for` loop IMHO.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye and Jean-Francois Fabre: Ok, than leave it at a dictionary, since that is what I'm using now.

Comment: I have posted an answer which works with any iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to take all items except the last:

```
from itertools import islice

a = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
for key, value in islice(a.iteritems(), len(a)-1 if a else None):
    ...
```

The ternary conditional helps to handle cases where `len(a)-1` gives a negative result i.e. dict is empty.

Comment: "it should work for any iterable". Hence `len` is forbidden.

Comment: In the end I found a construction which worked with the idea behind this answer: for i, (k,v) in enumerate( a.iteritems()): if i != len(a)-1: # do stuff

Comment: Looking at it now, this solution is that obvious that I should have thought of it at the start. I was thinking way too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Since it must work on any iterable, you cannot rely on `len`.

To be able to use a `for` loop, I would create an helper generator function which delays the `yield` until it knows if it's the last element or not.

If it's the last element, it returns `True` + key / value, else `False` + key / value

Proof of concept:

```
a = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }

def delayed_iterator(a):
    previous_v = None
    while True:
        v = next(a,None)
        if not v:
            yield True, previous_v
            break
        else:
            if previous_v:
                yield False, previous_v
            previous_v = v


for is_last, v in delayed_iterator(iter(a)):  # with iter, we make sure that it works with any iterable
    print(is_last,v,a[v])
```

output is:

```
False a 1
False b 2
True c 3
```

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a "first" or "last" key in a python dictionary because it doesn't preserve the insertion order of its elements when traversing it.

You could however use an **[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)** and recognize the last element like this:

```
import collections

a = collections.OrderedDict()
a['a'] = 1
a['b'] = 2
a['c'] = 3

for key, value in a.items():
    if(key != list(a.items())[-1][0]):
        # statements I want to skip when the current key, value pair is the last unprocessed pair in the dict.
```

Comment: Since people tend to focus on the dictionary in stead of on the for-loop I should have used another type which can be used in a for-loop, this since it is about the last value that the for-loop encounters and in case of the dict it does not care what that key-value pair is. Only that it is the last that the for-loop encounters.
for a list x=[1,2,3] that would be the 3, but for a dict it indeed can be anything. Maybe this clears it up a bit. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, normal dictionaries aren't ordered, so you need to use `OrderedDict` or array of tuples instead.

Secondly, why not just exclude the last element in the collection you loop over.

```
import collections

a = OrderedDict()
# add stuff to a

for key, value in a.items()[:-1]:
    # do something
```

Comment: I have to do most of the actions for all items in my for-loop. Just not for the last item (which is in this case a dict-entry, but could be any iterable).

Comment: @Nemelis When you don't even know what is going to be the last element, what's the logic in skipping it?

Comment: In this case it is some handling of files which is also done somewhere else for the last dict-pair, since for that last pair some other things have to be done as well before the file handling needs to be done. Again the actual pair does not matter, only that it is the last pair in the for-loop.